# Conditional access for Personal account Azure AD application

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, multi-factor-authentication

i have a requirement to enable MFA for Azure Ad application. the application is registered to support Personal account only

When i try to configure conditional access policy, i dont see the app in "Cloud apps". even if i choose all apps options, the policy is not getting enforced for the app

how do i my requirement for enforcing MFA for Personal accounts app

Answer (score 0):

***AFAIK, you cannot configure Conditional Access to the application that is registered to support Personal account only.***

You can configure Conditional Access to applications that appear in **Enterprise Applications** list only.

When you registered an application with **`Personal Microsoft accounts only`** type, service principal won't be created, and it won't appear in **Enterprise applications** list.

So, you cannot find your app in **Cloud Apps** section even you selected 'All Cloud Apps'.

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got same results as you:***

I registered an application with **`Personal Microsoft accounts only`** type like below:

[image]

When I tried to configure **Conditional Access** for it, I can't find that application in 'Select Apps' like below:

[image]

So, even you selected 'All Cloud Apps' option and configured the **Conditional Access** policy, it won't be applied on your app.

You can refer this **[Microsoft Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/conditional-access/concept-conditional-access-cloud-apps)** that includes the list of applications supported for **Conditional Access** in detail that will appear in Cloud Apps.

Comment: so if i want to do CA for users of Personal "Microsoft accounts app", how do i achieve it?

Comment: ***AFAIK***, unfortunately you can't do that for now as personal Microsoft accounts apps are not supported for CA. You can raise a **feature request** for the same.